# How to get the list of unsubscribers emails from mailchimp

Tags: api, mailchimp

I want to get the emails of unsubscribers the code below returning the count that how many of it are there but how could i get the List of unsubscribers from output variable...

Here is my full code::

```
private List<campaignUnsubscribesResults.Unsubscribes> Unsubscribers = new List<campaignUnsubscribesResults.Unsubscribes>();

 private void GetUnsubscribers(string apikey, string MailChimpCampaignID)
        {

            campaignUnsubscribesInput input = new campaignUnsubscribesInput();
            input.api_AccessType = PerceptiveMCAPI.EnumValues.AccessType.Serial;
            input.api_CustomErrorMessages = true;
            input.api_MethodType = PerceptiveMCAPI.EnumValues.MethodType.POST;
            input.api_Validate = true;
            input.api_OutputType = PerceptiveMCAPI.EnumValues.OutputType.XML;
            input.parms.apikey = apikey;
            input.parms.cid = MailChimpCampaignID;

            //input.parms.start = PageIndex;
            //input.parms.limit = PageSize;

            campaignUnsubscribes unsubscribe = new campaignUnsubscribes();
            campaignUnsubscribesOutput output = unsubscribe.Execute(input);

            Unsubscribers.AddRange(output.result.data);
            string unsubscriber = "0";

            //ArrayList a = new ArrayList(); 
            //a[0] = output.result.data.ToString();
            //List<MCItem> lst = new List<MCItem>();

            //            foreach (listBatchUnsubscribeResults order in myArrayList)  
            //{  
            //     orders.add(order);  
            //} 
            string[] unsubs;

            //ArrayList [] list = new ArrayList [0];
            foreach (listMembers list1 in output.result)
            {
                unsubscriber = list1.ToString();
            }

            string unsubscribers = Unsubscribers.Count.ToString();

            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "alert", "<script language=JavaScript>alert('Unsubscribers::  '+ ' " + unsubscribers + " ');</script>");
            //Unsubscribers.Reverse();
            //dlUnsubscribes.DataSource = Unsubscribers.Take(10);
            //dlUnsubscribes.DataBind();

            //dlUnsubscribes.Visible = (Unsubscribers.Count > 0);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Mailchimp Webhooks](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/webhooks/). You setup a page/script on your website which will get called by Mailchimp every time a particular event occurs. When it's an unsubscribe event, you can log the info you want to store to a database, file, etc.